# What is the proper way to getInitialState with remote data in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, react-alt

**IT IS SOLVED.** The code was ok, the problem was with improper import.

It is a long post (due to code samples). I'll appreciate your patience and will be very thankful for your help!

We have a RoR back-end and React on the front-end and we are using alt as an implementation of flux. We also use babel to compile ES6 to ES5. So the problem is that I can not render component due to 2 errors.

First is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

It appears on the render function of MapPalette component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.featureCategories.map(fc => <PaletteItemsList featureCategory={fc} />)}
    </div>
    );
}
```

And the second is `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: receiveComponent(...): Can only update a mounted component.`

So here is the whole MapPalette component

```
"use strict";
import React from 'react';
import PaletteItemsList from './PaletteItemsList';
import FeatureCategoryStore from '../stores/FeatureTypeStore';

function getAppState() {
  return {
    featureCategories: FeatureCategoryStore.getState().featureCategories
  };
}

var MapPalette = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'MapPalette',

  propTypes: {
    featureSetId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return getAppState();
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    FeatureCategoryStore.listen(this._onChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    FeatureCategoryStore.unlisten(this._onChange);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.featureCategories.map(fc => <PaletteItemsList featureCategory={fc} />)}
      </div>
      );
  },

  _onChange() {
    this.setState(getAppState());
  }

});

module.exports = MapPalette;
```

FeatureCategoryStore

```
var featureCategoryStore = alt.createStore(class FeatureCategoryStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(FeatureCategoryActions)
    this.featureCategories = [];
  }

  onReceiveAll(featureCategories) {
    this.featureCategories = featureCategories;
  }

})

module.exports = featureCategoryStore
```

FeatureCategoryActions

```
class FeatureCategoryActions {
  receiveAll(featureCategories) {
    this.dispatch(featureCategories)
  }

  getFeatureSetCategories(featureSetId) {
    var url = '/feature_categories/nested_feature_types.json';
    var actions = this.actions;
    this.dispatch();

    request.get(url)
           .query({ feature_set_id: featureSetId })
           .end( function(response) {
             actions.receiveAll(response.body);
           });
  }
}

module.exports = alt.createActions(FeatureCategoryActions);
```

And the last - how I render React component.

```
var render = function() {
    FeatureCategoryActions.getFeatureSetCategories(#{ @feature_set.id });
    React.render(
      React.createElement(FeatureSetEditMap, {featureSetId: #{@feature_set.id}}),
      document.getElementById('react-app')
    )
  }
```

Comment: firstly, prepare the loop outside of the return block, ie create a new variable and then save the contents of `this.state.featureCategories.map(fc => <PaletteItemsList featureCategory={fc} />` in the render function but not in the return block. Then use that variable inside the <div></div> of the return part

Comment: @KoustuvSinha Why would you do that? I think it reads much better the way it's done now.

Comment: it reads better, yes but it would be easier to debug if you construct the array before returning thats all

Comment: That's a good point, even if I wouldn't structure my code for ease of debugging. You might want to edit the comment to reflect that, because currently your comment reads as if that is something related to OPs problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for your wasted time on reading it, but I figured it out and the reason of trouble was my silly mistake in importing. Essentially, I've imported another Store with the name of needed.

So, instead of `import FeatureCategoryStore from '../stores/FeatureTypeStore';`

It should be `import FeatureCategoryStore from '../stores/FeatureCategoryStore';`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the first error you get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Is because `this.state` in your component is undefined, which means that you probably haven't implemented `getInitialState` in your component.

You haven't included the full implementation of your component, which we need to see to be able to help you. But let's walk through their example of a view component:

```
var LocationComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return locationStore.getState()
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    locationStore.listen(this.onChange)
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    locationStore.unlisten(this.onChange)
  },

  onChange() {
    this.setState(this.getInitialState())
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          City {this.state.city}
        </p>
        <p>
          Country {this.state.country}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

They implement `getInitialState` here to return the current state of the store, which you'll then be able to use in the `render` method. In `componentDidMount`, they listen to change events from that store so that any events occuring in that store coming from anywhere in your application will trigger a re-render. `componentWillUnmount` cleans up the event listener. Very important not to forget this, or your app will leak memory! Next the `onChange` method (which could be have whatever name, it's not an internal React method), which the store will call when a change event occurs. This just sets the state of the component to whatever the stores state is. Might be a bit confusing that they call `getInitialState` again here, because you're not getting the initial state, you're getting the current state of the store.

Another important note here is that this example won't work off the bat with ES6/ES2015 classes, because React no longer autobinds methods to the instance of the component. So the example implemented as a class would look something like this:

```
class LocationComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = this.getState();

    this.onChangeListener = () => this.setState(this.getState());
  }

  getState() {
    return locationStore.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    locationStore.listen(this.onChangeListener);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    locationStore.unlisten(this.onChangeListener)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          City {this.state.city}
        </p>
        <p>
          Country {this.state.country}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: great explanation! can you share a fiddle? :)

Comment: Thanks for explanations! I've updated my question with full implementation of the component. I do not understand why the state is undefined. Because from the console I can see that this call `FeatureCategoryActions.getFeatureSetCategories(#{ @feature_set.id });` Sends a request and getting expected response.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(FeatureCategoryStore.getState().featureCategories)` in your `getAppState` function to see that it contains what you expect.

Comment: Then that's the reason you get the first error. Does `console.log(FeatureCategoryStore.getState())` yield undefined as well?

Comment: Nope, It show and object. FeatureCategory object. I thought it should be an array with that object?

Comment: I haven't used alt and don't know enough about your code to answer that unfortunately.

Comment: Okay. Anyway, thank you very much for your help, patience and attention!